# Scrolling Menu is Not Working in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, vector

This is the code for my scrolling menu where it display different values based on the 3 vectors, welcomeMenuVector, menuOptionsVector and menuActionVector:

> **welcomeMenuVector** - Save function of title
>
> **menuOptionsVector** - Save menu options of scrolling menu
>
> **menuActionsVector** - Save the functions to perform after the menu option is selected

```
vector<string> menuOptionsVector;
vector<function<void()>> menuActionsVector;
vector<function<void()>> welcomeMenuVector;

void scrollingMenu(){
    ShowConsoleCursor(false);

    int pointer = 0;

    while (true){
        system("cls");

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);

        welcomeMenuVector[0]();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < menuOptionsVector.size(); ++i){
            if (i == pointer){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 14); 
                cout << center("> " + menuOptionsVector[i] + " <" ,getWindowWidth()) <<endl;
            }
            else{
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
                cout << center("  " + menuOptionsVector[i] + "  ", getWindowWidth()) << endl;
            }
        }

        while (true){
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0){
                pointer -= 1;

                if (pointer == -1){
                    pointer = menuOptionsVector.size() - 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0){
                pointer += 1;

                if (pointer == menuOptionsVector.size()){
                    pointer = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0){ //when enter key is pressed
                menuActionsVector[pointer]();
            }
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I will need to enter menu title, menu options and menu functions into vector before I need to call the **scrollingMenu()**. Hence, I will have to clear all the 3 vectors before entering values into vectors because there will be values inside as it might be used by another menu earlier.

---

This is my main page, user page and add user page:

```
void mainPage(){
    clearMenuVectors();

    welcomeMenuVector = { [](){mainPageWelcome(); } };

    menuOptionsVector = { "Login", "Exit" };

    menuActionsVector = {
        [](){ userPage(); },
        [](){ exit(0); }
    };

    scrollingMenu();
}

void userPage(){
    clearMenuVectors();

    welcomeMenuVector = { [](){userPageWelcome(); } };

    menuOptionsVector = { "Add User", "Update User", "Delete User", "Exit" };

    menuActionsVector = {
        [](){ addUsers(); },
        [](){ updateUsers(); },
        [](){ deleteUsers(); },
        [](){ exit(0); }
    };

    scrollingMenu();
}

void addUsers(){

    clearMenuVectors();

    welcomeMenuVector = { [](){cout << center("Which type of user would you like to add?", getWindowWidth()) << endl;; } };

    menuOptionsVector = { "Add Admin", "Add Scheduler", "Add Professional", "Exit" };

    menuActionsVector = {
        [](){ /*addUser();*/ },
        [](){ /*updateUsers();*/ },
        [](){ /*deleteUsers();*/ },
        [](){ exit(0); }
    };
}
```

---

My main page works fine at first, I'm able to move up & down, after hitting enter on the **Login** menu option, it goes to the **userPage**, but here comes the problem, when I'm in the **userPage**, I can still see the menu options of **userPage**, but when I just move up/down it will then changed the menu options of **addUsers** (I haven't even hit the enter), even if I dont move up/down I hit enter on **Add User** option, nothing happens, I'm not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: Nicely asked. This is how a question should look on SO.

Comment: small optimization: rather than calling ``GetStdHandle`` multiple times in a loop, why not invoke it before your loop and use that handle instead

Comment: @Asesh sorry, I don't really get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
 [](){ /*addUser();*/ },
```

to 
     { cout << "add user option 1" << endl; },

and it writes it continuously then the key is pressed.

[GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

> whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit
>   is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the
>   key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

So you need to check the least significant bit. In this case

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
```

should be

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x1)
```

Comment: Hi Surt, there's another problem in my scrolling menu again, I couldn't figure out what's the problem.

Now I've added new menuActions which will be taking values from users:

cout << "Enter User's Name: " << endl;
 getline(cin, name);

and now the problem is it wont allow user to enter value, and it just print the question only. At first was thinking adding a break to the scrollingmenu function in after enter keypressed section, but it's still not solving.

Comment: and after I hit enter after the cin, it continues ask me to input the same cin again, which it seems like not breaking out the loop :(

Comment: seems like there will be problem if I'm using GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) and cin in the same time, I think I'll change the (VK_RETURN) to (VK_RCONTROL), which I'll make the ctrl key act as a enter key, hence there'll not be too much of conflicts.